# Evil spellcaster theory crafting

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spellcasting

I'm thinking about building an evil spellcaster - abusing the Damnation Feats, especially [Maleficium](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/damnation-feats/maleficium-damnation/) since DC increases are quite rare but very useful so I'd like to try build something around this.

However looking at spells with the Evil descriptor (you can filter them [here](https://aonprd.com/SpellsCustom.aspx)) there aren't actually many offensive spells that even have a DC and either deal good damage or cause some crippling effect. So I'm looking into ways to add the descriptor to spells that aren't normally evil. So far I found:

- [Apocalyptic Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/apocalyptic-spell-metamagic/)
- [Stygian Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/stygian-spell-metamagic/)
- [Demonic Mark](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/c-d/demoniac/)

Apocalyptic Spell is quite useful but it would be nice to also have something for single-target spells.

Stygian seems not very good since very few spells have the required water descriptor.

Dip into Demoniac is bad because of losing spell level progression (yeah I'm aware you can negate that with two feats - too high a price) and it's just one spell per day regardless.

Anything else that can be used? Maybe I missed some subclass or archetype that can add the evil descriptor?

---

I'm also interested in other useful synergies that can affect / improve evil spells in particular. Also which existing evil spells would you consider particularly useful? I was considering combining Maleficium with [Spell Specialist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/archetypes/paizo-arcanist-archetypes/spell-specialist) and [Potent Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/arcane-exploits/potent-magic-su) which would already be DC +5 before Spell Focus, making the spells very difficult to resist.

At this point I don't care too much whether it's divine or arcane spellcasting class, just want to know about some useful synergies.

Note: Our campaign is limited to Paizo material but other sources may be included as honorable mentions for other players.

Answer (score 3):

#### Your analysis of demoniac, Apocalyptic, and Stygian is accurate

Apocalyptic Spell is absolutely the way to go here, out of these three. The others are badly limited and thus complete non-starters. Apocalyptic **also** has a number of deeply-limiting requirements (area spell, instantaneous spell), but they’re a lot broader than Stygian’s (water spell), and the 1 spell level cost is much better than just 1/day, period.

#### There are no other evil-granting metamagic feats

I checked both d20pfsrd.com and aorprd.com for metamagic feats that use the word “evil,” and both turned up just 5 results:

- Apocalyptic Spell
- Blissful Spell
- Consecrate Spell
- Solar Spell
- Stygian Spell

As might be expected, Blissful, Consecrate, and Solar are good, and they use the word “evil” to specify that they do things to evil creatures and/or aren’t allowed on evil spells. Apocalyptic and Stygian are the only ones that add the evil descriptor.

For the curious, I searched with:

- d20pfsrd.com—this Google query: [`site:https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/ evil`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.d20pfsrd.com%2Ffeats%2Fmetamagic-feats%2F+evil)
- aonprd.com—can’t use a `site:` query because aorprd.com doesn’t indicate that a feat is metamagic in the URL. Instead used the following code in my browser Console while on [the aonprd Metamagic Feat index page](https://aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?Category=Metamagic):

  ```
  (await Promise.all(
    [...new Set(
      [...document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName="]')]
        .map(a => a.href)
    )].map(
      async (href) => [
        href,
        (await (await fetch(href)).text())
      ]
    )
  ))
    .filter(([href, body]) => /evil/i.test(body))
    .map(([href, body]) => href)
  ```

  This goes through the list of links on that page, pulling each one and checking its text for any instance of the word “evil,” returning the URL of any pages that have it.

Both methods turned up the same 5 feats.

#### Non-metamagic and/or non-feat options

I haven’t managed to come up with a solid search pattern to try to rule out all classes, prestige classes, and archetypes, or even non-metamagic feats.

But for what it’s with, a search of [`site:https://www.d20pfsrd.com/ "evil descriptor"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.d20pfsrd.com%2F+%22evil+descriptor%22) turned up some synergies, below, but not any alternative methods of making spells evil in the first place.

#### Maleficium itself might largely solve your problem

If you have another Damnation feat on top of Maleficium, you get

> When you apply a metamagic feat to a spell with the evil descriptor, that spell takes up a spell slot 1 level lower than normal (to a minimum of 1 level above the spell’s actual level).

This applies each time you use a metamagic feat—meaning it can apply multiple times to the same spell if you use multiple metamagic feats on it. And since the minimum level adjustment is 1 level above the spell’s *actual level*—and other than Heighten Spell, metamagic doesn’t change a spell’s *actual level*—we can add Apocalyptic Spell for free so long as we are also adding other metamagic feats that add at least 1 to the spell’s level.

This is abuse. Most GMs will probably nix it. But RAW, it works out.

#### Other Synergies

Some other things that improve evil spells or give you extra benefits for casting them:

- [Dark Magic Affinity](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/dark-magic-affinity-tiefling/): +1 to evil spells’ caster level for tieflings.
- [Summon Evil Monster](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/summon-evil-monster): Provides lists of evil monsters you can summon with a standard-action casting of *summon monster*. *Summon monster* garbage with a 1-round casting time, so if you want to summon monsters, definitely grab this. That said, it doesn’t really benefit from Maleficium or any of the other synergies I’ve found, so it’s kinda tangential here.
- [Wretched Curator](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/story-feats/wretched-curator-story/): 10% discount on evil scrolls and potions, and some skill bonuses related to the use of evil items. If you jump through some extra hoops, you can either remove the evil descriptor from spells (boo), or gain 2 temporary hit points per spell level every time you cast an evil spell without removing the descriptor.
- [*Candle of Abaddon*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/c-d/candle-of-abaddon/): +2 to evil spells’ caster level, lasts 4 hours.
- [*Orb of Foul Abaddon*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/m-p/orb-of-foul-abaddon/): +1 to evil spells’ caster level, and 1/day free casting of *dread bolt*.
- [*The Book of the Damned*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/artifacts/major-artifacts/book-of-the-damned-original/): a major artifact, which means you probably will never see it. Tons of relevant effects, though, including +2 to the caster level of evil spells.

Dark Magic Affinity is worth being a tiefling for, and *orb of foul Abaddon* is definitely worth it. Obviously *The Book of the Damned* is massively powerful. I’d give Wretched Curator and *candle of Abaddon* a pass, though, personally. Summon Evil Monster, too—it’s great if you really want to summon, but summoning is kinda eh.

#### D&D 3.5e options

The *Book of Vile Darkness* includes Corrupt Spell and Violate Spell. Both apply the same +1 spell level cost that Apocalyptic Spell does, but neither has any requirements about the sorts of spells they may be applied to. That makes them superior to Apocalyptic Spell for these purposes (even though I like the actual effect of Apocalyptic Spell better for those spells it works on).

There are also other metamagic-cost-reducing options to make these easier to apply to all of your spells. The most infamous—and overpowered—option is incantatrix from *Player’s Guide to Faerûn*, which specializes in metamagic and can apply a **ton** of it very cheaply. Easy Metamagic (*Dragon* vol. 325—a Paizo publication!) and Practical Metamagic (*Races of the Dragon*) are pretty solid choices for a metamagic specialist, though neither helps any of the evil-ifying feats since they both have a minimum of +1 spell level. Arcane Thesis (*Complete Arcane*) is another overpowered option, though not nearly as overpowered as incantatrix, that can be used very, very well if you have one specific spell you want to specialize in (*enervation* is traditional).

D&D 3.5e also allows Spell Focus to choose “evil” to apply to all evil spells. Obviously valuable here. Spell Focus (evil) is also a prerequisite for the notorious ur-priest prestige class (*Complete Divine*), which can get 9th-level spells from the cleric list as early as 15th level without early-entry shenanigans.

Comment: A number of spells can gain the `Evil` descriptor in certain circumstances; the Summon Monster line comes to mind, and https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/summon-evil-monster looks like an interesting option.

Comment: @minnmass Interesting, but man, so many caveats on that ability. Standard-action *summon monster* isn’t **that** good, Paizo, relax! Anyway, it doesn’t really benefit from Maleficium or any of the other synergy here, so it’s kinda... related, but not directly a part of this optimization project. I’ll include it for completeness; I guess Maleficium could get you some metamagic on it... though most metamagic doesn’t work on summons...

Comment: It does lessen the pain of quicken, slightly… Mostly, I could have sworn there were other spells that changed their type like Summons do, but I can’t find ‘em.

Comment: @minnmass You can’t quicken *summon monster*: “A spell whose casting time is more than 1 full-round action cannot be quickened.” Not that it’d ever be worth it at +4 spell levels. 3.5e had Rapid Spell for +1, that reduced long casting times by 1 round, and made 1-round casting times into full-round actions (i.e. still took your whole turn, but at least the summon showed up **this turn** instead of next turn). Still wasn’t worth it, though; the only reason it’s notable is because of the *metamagic rod*. Pathfinder seems to be lacking anything comparable for some inane reason, though.

Comment: Summon evil monster makes it a standard action, bringing Quicken into the mix. Still painful at +3, though.

Comment: @minnmass _In theory_, you could pull the cheese that Arcane Thesis made famous in 3.5e: apply a couple of +0 metamagics, so Maleficium reduces the spell level by 1 each time (to a minimum of +1 above the spell’s _actual level_). So with Maleficium and another Damnation feat, *summon monster III* is 3rd-level, *quickened summon monster III* is 6th-level (+3), *fleeting quickened summon monster III* is 5th-level (−1), and *tenebrous fleeting quickened monster III* is 4th-level (−1). Which isn’t terrible, but not amazing for five feats and a 4th-level spell slot.

Answer (score 1):

### DC increases aren't that rare

With Spell Focus & Greater Spell Focus, as well as typical caster headbands with enhancement bonuses to your casting ability (INT, WIS, CHA), there are already base options for DC increases available to everyone. Most full casters classes also offer some way to increase the DC, so these increases aren't that rare.

### Evil & Damage

Damage spells are usually Fire spells, especially with entire character builds made around D&D/PF's signature spell *Fireball*.

I think Apocalyptic Spell is a good start, but if you seek more versatility, consider building around [Stygian Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/stygian-spell-metamagic/#) metamagic. You're right, there are very few good spells with the Water descriptor, but there are many good spells with the Fire descriptor. There are two different ways to deal with that:

### Steam Caster

You can transform Fire spells into Water spells with the Undine's [Steam Caster](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/steam-caster-undine/#) racial feat. It's not a metamagic feat, and the increase to a full-round action casting time therefore affects every caster, even Wizards & Arcanists. Since spells with a casting time of 1 full-round action or more are not increased further, it doesn't matter whether you do it with a prepared or spontaneous caster (or a hybrid like the Arcanist).

You would need to be an [Undine](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-undine/#) or have the [Planar Heritage (Undine)](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Planar%20Heritage) feat, which is available to Humans and all characters who count as Humans (Half-Elves, Half-Orcs, Outsiders with the "mostly human" alternate racial trait, …).

### Benthic Spell

The [Benthic Spell metamagic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/benthic-spell-metamagic/#) allows you to transform any spell that deals fire/cold/acid/electricity damage into a Water spell, at the expense of a +1 spell-level adjustment. It's a rarely used metamagic, not so much because it's useless, but usually because there are stronger feats. In your case of needing Water spells and seeking to add more metamagics, it works though and can even be a good source of bypassing immunities to energy types.

The [Brackish Spell metamagic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/brackish-spell-metamagic/) is a pretty weak feat, but maybe useful for Water spell metamagics, since it has a +0 spell-level adjustment.

### Bloodlines

The Sorcerer's [Elemental bloodline](https://www.aonprd.com/BloodlineDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Elemental) can transform any spell with energy damage (including other energy types like sonic) into your element, while the [Marid bloodline](https://www.aonprd.com/BloodlineDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Marid) can do the same for Water (and [Efreeti](https://www.aonprd.com/BloodlineDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Efreeti) for Fire, …).

The bloodline arcanas need to be looked at carefully, as they talk about descriptors (plural); there are energy type descriptors (fire, cold, acid, electricity) and element type descriptors (fire, water, earth, air) respectively, with the fire descriptor being the same for both types – which is sometimes confusing. [see the [elemental bloodline]](https://www.aonprd.com/BloodlineDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Elemental)

So these bloodlines would not just turn the damage to cold damage and the [fire, acid, electricity] descriptors into the [cold] descriptor, but also turn [fire, earth, air] descriptors into the [water] descriptor, thereby allowing you to use Stygian Spell on pretty much any fire spell and many spells with energy damage.

You would need to be a Sorcerer or dip 1 level into Sorcerer.

Arcanists can make use of the entire bloodline with the [Bloodline Development exploit](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist/arcane-exploits/bloodline-development/#), though since the bloodline powers are weak on the elemental bloodlines, better dip 1 level into Crossblooded Sorcerer and also take the [Arcane bloodline](https://www.aonprd.com/BloodlineDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Arcane), as the bloodline arcana adds another +1 DC when using a metamagic and the School Power bloodline power grants a further +2 DC to a school of magic (e.g. Evocation).

### Spell Perfection

If you have a favorite spell, strongly consider the [Spell Perfection](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spell%20Perfection) feat at level 15, not just for a free metamagic, but also since it doubles the effects of set variables gained from other feats on that spell, i.e. it would double the DC bonus from Maleficium.

Comment: Headbands are as good as mandatory for any spellcaster so they don't count. My previous spellcaster had SF, GSF and Arcane Bloodline and bosses still saved more often than not. The point is there aren't many DC increases available beyond these obvious ones.

Comment: Bosses aren't meant to be taken down with a single save-or-X spell – that's a team effort. DC increase options aren't rare, and if they don't suffice, then have your allies buff you up, or have the party engage in bonus removal (e.g. Studied Spell metamagic) and applying penalty debuffs that reduce saves (e.g. Shaken, Sickened, …). Only a select few spellcasters can raise their DCs high enough to not need a party's help to land their save-or-X spell, e.g. Kitsune/Half-Elf Enchanter Sorcerers.